# jQuery - Access elements in array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I need to be able to get the width of elements from an array

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <ul>
     <li id="one">--------</li><br />
     <li id="two">----------------</li><br />
     <li id="three">-------</li><br />
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS

I know i can access the individual width's like this

```
$('#one').width();
```

But in an array

```
var $array = $("#container li");
```

How do i access a specific width of the element by its index

e.g

```
$array[2].width(); //which causes error
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/8zvkn/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) :

```
$('#container li').eq(i)
```

Comment: Yes the problem with OP oringal attempt using `$array[2]`. Is that `$array[2]` is a DOM element not a jQuery object, so you can't perform `width()` on it.  Using `eq()` you get a filtered jQuery object for the element at that index.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `.eq` function like below,

```
$array.eq(2).width()
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8zvkn/2/

`$array[2]` - returns DOM element but what you need is the jQuery object which has the `.width` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this using nth-child:

```
$("#container li:nth-child(1)").width(); // first li
```